# The Component for route must be a react component error in React native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am new to react native and I was trying to connect reduxstore to my app so that my Menu component may fetch the dishes.
I have tried everything checked for the export errors but yet I couldn't find where is the route missing.
Please help I'm stuck

MenuComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import { Tile } from "react-native-elements";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { baseUrl } from "../shared/baseUrl";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    dishes: state.dishes
  }
};

class Menu extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Menu"
  };

  render() {
    const renderMenuItem = ({ item, index }) => {
      return (
        <Tile
          key={index}
          title={item.name}
          subtitle={item.description}
          featured
          onPress={() => navigate("Dishdetail", { dishId: item.id })}
          imageSrc={{ uri: baseUrl + item.image }}
        />
      );
    };

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.dishes.dishes}
        renderItem={renderMenuItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu);
```

MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "./MenuComponent";
import { DISHES } from "../shared/dishes";
import Dishdetail from "./DishdetailComponent";
import {
  View,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Text
} from "react-native";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerItems,
  SafeAreaView
} from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./HomeComponent";
import Contact from "./ContactComponent";
import About from "./AboutComponent";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  fetchDishes,
  fetchComments,
  fetchPromos,
  fetchLeaders
} from "../Redux/ActionCreators";

..... 
const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {
      screen: Menu,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            name="menu"
            size={24}
            color="white"
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        )
      })
    },
    Dishdetail: { screen: Dishdetail }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Menu",
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"
      }
    }
  }
);
.....


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Main);
```

Error message

```
The component for route 'Menu' must be a React component for example:

import MyScreen from './Myscreen'
...

Menu : Myscreen,
}

you can also use a navigator:

    import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
    ....
    Menu : MyNavigator
    }

    validateRouteConfigMap

    createStackNavigator
```

I dont understand why I'm getting error for menu component because I have exported it successfully.
The error has also something to do with createStackNavigator but I think the code looks fine, if not then what am I doing worng?

Comment: How are you using MenuNavigator?

Comment: Try  import in  curly braces : 
import { Menu } from "./MenuComponent";

Comment: I am using menu navigator as my home screen for the app.

Comment: importing like this {Menu} didn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your screen is properly setting `export default`.

Could you change this code?

```js
const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {
      screen: () => <Menu />,
```

Comment: I will try this